# Retrieve SQL statements - No backup, No query tracing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I know that my question probably don't belong here but I would be really so thankful if someone has the skill for solving this out.

I have recently made several `update` statements that I shouldn't have done and would like to see their queries with parameters or at least something so I could retrieve the data back manually.

I'm able to access `::fn_dblog(NULL, NULL)` and I would like to know if can I see the queries with parameters from there?

It could have been cca 200 statements.

I'm using SQL server 2012.

I don't have backup or query tracing ony my server.

Comment: @PaulWhite I have changed data in one of the tables so I would like to retrieve them as they were before the update statement. Is it possible somehow please?

Comment: @PaulWhite No I don't I mentioned that in the title.

Answer (score 1):

See if the query plans are still in cache.

Adjust the datetime and query filter to suit what you know about the queries you ran

```
SELECT dest.text 
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs 
cross APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest 
where deqs.last_execution_time > '15 may 2014 14:00' 
and dest.text LIKE '%UPDATE%'
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your fast reply, but I cannot see those queries anymore, basically my problem is that I updated data in table and would like to retrieve them back. Is it possible somehow please? I would be really thankful.